# How to change dynamically tabe cell text colors?

Tags: javascript, html

I need a solution to change dynamically via javascript the text color of table cells. The text can be the following colors: blue, green, red and black.

Table example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"       type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="content">
      <table width="100%" border="0" id="friends" class="menu">
        <tr id="friend1">
          <td>First name</td>
          <td>Surname</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="friend2">
          <td>First name</td>
          <td>Surname</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="friend3">
          <td>First name</td>
          <td>Surname</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="friend4">
          <td>First name</td>
          <td>Surname</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="friend5">
          <td>First name</td>
          <td>Surname</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I change the text color? Conditions are, that I could do this dynamically via javascript and more than one time. That means I need to set a color (e.g. red), later reset the color to black and set it following to another color (e.g. blue).

I saw some examples with setting the color via id, but I found no way to transfer this example to table cells and each cell could have different colors.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can go through all td's

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for(var i = 0, j = tds.length; i < j; ++i)
   tds[i].style.color = "#00AA00";
```

OR

you can go through td's that are childs of a special element:

```
var myNode = document.getElementById("friend2");
var tds = myNode.getElementsByTagName("td");

    for(var i = 0, j = tds.length; i < j; ++i)
       tds[i].style.color = "#00AA00";
```

greetings!

Comment: Hi Mic, thank you for this solution. I tried it and it works :-).

Answer (score 3):

create a class for each color in your css file:

```
.redCell{
    color:red;
}
.blueCell{
    color:blue;
}
.yellowCell...
```

then, add the class to the TD you need:

```
$('#friend01').addClass('blueCell');
```

if you need to remove the color:

```
$('#friend01').removeClass('blueCell');
```

if you need to know if a cell has a certain color:

```
$('#friend01').hasClass('blueCell');
```

Comment: nice way to do this with jquery but you always have to know what "color" - class currently is given to the object or if you set a new class you have to remove all known classes. Example: if you have a green, a blue, a yellow, a red, a blue and a black "color" - class you have to remove all of them with `$('#friend01').removeClass('...');` to be sure no conflicts are there with other classes. If you add a new color you have to add it in your code. i think it is a good but complicated way when you add new classes.

Comment: I see no problem. To remove all classes you could create a "resetColors" function that removes all color classes. Another way is to keep track of the color each cell has and making sure each cell has only one class, for example with a global array.

Comment: First of all thank you for helping :-). I tried this solution, but it does not work at my side. If I expend my table cell with `<tr id="friend1"><td id="friend1a">First name</td><td id="friend1b">Surname</td></tr>` and call `$('#friend1b').addClass('blue');` the text is not blue as expected.

Comment: @Thomas you must be doing something else wrong. This solution works well. here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4wxnq/2/  just click on the "clickMe" p and the text will change color.

Comment: @Th0rndike: You are right, it works at your fiddle. Hmm, I really do not know what I am doing wrong. I will check this! Thank you for your solution and the fiddle :-).