# Change table col text color with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the text color of a table col depending on the numerical value of each cell. 
If the number is bigger than 0, the text color should turn green, if it's smaller than 0 it should turn red.

I have only little experience with scripting so I'm not really surprised that my script does't work. Help is very much appreciated.

This is what I'm using right now:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col>
        <col id="changerow">
        <col>
        <col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <!-- here is the table -->
    </tbody>
</table>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('changerow');
    var cng = document.getElementById('changerow').innerHTML;

    if (cng > 0) {
        cng.document.getElementById('changerow').innerHTML.style.color = green;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: smaller than zero? use `<` instead.

Comment: I do not see any value in `cell`!

Comment: I cut the cell part out of the code to make it shorter.
My goal is to not individually target the single cells but instead use the col  (id=changerow) to check for every cell in this particular col.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265899/how-to-change-dynamically-tabe-cell-text-colors Hi hope above link will be suits for your expectations.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm still not sure how to check the numeric value inside the table cell. That ( stackoverflow.com/questions/13265899/) guy just wanted the change the trs/tds dynamically but without the condition of checking every cell for >0 or <0.

Comment: `<!--
 var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
 var converted = parseFloat(tds);
for(var i = 0, j = tds.length; i < j; ++i)
   if(converted > 0){
    tds[i].style.color = "#FFFFFF";
   }

-->`
I edited the code from your link like that. Still not getting there. Any ideas?